# Dealing with XElement null value

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml that I am querying.  One of the nodes is missing.  So when I call XElement.Value I get a null exception.

What is the best way to guard against this?  I know I can write an extension method, but I am wondering is there something build into the language for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the null coalesce operator `??`

Given an `XElement` elem:

```
var value = (string)elem ?? "empty";
```

Comment: That's the right answer, but it's worth pointing out that the important bit here is really that `XElement`'s explicit conversion to string will return null if the input is null - whereas `element.Value` will throw an exception.

Comment: so assuming XElement is null.  string myvalue = (string) XElement;  will have myvalue be null?  string myvalue = XElement.Value; will throw an exception.  string myvalue = (string) XElement ?? "empty"; will give myvalue a value of "empty"?